# In F#, how can I access attributes on a function?

Tags: reflection, f#, attributes

Say I am creating an attribute in F# and I apply it to a function as follows:

```
type MyAttribute(value: int) =
    inherit System.Attribute()
    member this.Value = value

[<My(42)>]
let myFunction() = ()
```

How can I retrieve that attribute via reflection?

Ideally I would like to use something along the lines of `myFunction.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true)` but that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myFunction.GetType()` does not work because the F# compiler automatically creates an `FSharpFunc<_,_>` subclass each time you reference a function. You'd be getting the type of the `FSharpFunc`, which is not what you need.

To get a function's reflection info, you'd need to find the module in which it lives first. Each module is compiled to a static class, and you can find the function inside that class. So, to get this function:

```ml
module MyModule

let myFunc x = x + 1
```

you'd need to do something like this (I didn't check the code):

```ml
// Assuming the code is in the same assembly as the function;
// otherwise, you must find the assembly in which the module lives
let assm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
let moduleType = assm.GetType("MyModule")
let func = moduleType.GetMethod("myFunc")
let attrib = func.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>()
```

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to do this at runtime? Rather than going from the module name at build time, can I go from the `FSharpFunc` instance back to the module somehow?

Comment: If there is a good way, I don't know it. You could always get the `Invoke` method's body IL and look through it for the function it calls, but that's as not good as solutions ever get.